# Export SQL database diagram to image with Persian(or Arabic) description

Tags: sql, diagram

I want export database diagram to image and for this I right click on diagram, then select 
**copy diagram to clipboard**. When paste in Paint, my Persian(or Arabic) description convert to set of **?** char. Haw can I export database diagram with Persian description to image ?